# How to search for class that has dot in its name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an element with class "4.0.3" how can I search for it?

ff 12.x & latest chrome returns nothing for

```
console.log($('.4\.0\.3').length);
console.log($(".4.0.3").length);
```

On the other hand `.hasClass()` correctly returns if the element got a class that contains `.`

Comment: Since ``\`` is the escape character in strings as well, `'5\.4'` results in the string `5.4`. Try: `console.log('5\.4')`. So, `'5\.4'` and `'5.4'` create the same string value.

Comment: That's why the backslash must be doubled, right?

Comment: Yes, you have to escape the escape character to create a literal backslash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape it with double back-slash

```
$('.4\\.0\\.3')
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\

Comment: @zerkms - RE: your deleted comment, RE: my deleted answer... but the dot character (`.`) is `U+002E`, which is, of course, less than `U+00A0`.  So, not allowed, right?  I mean, I see that [in practice it works... sort of](http://jsfiddle.net/VcWfb/), but it shouldn't according to CSS naming rules, right?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @gilly3: Yep, In some unknown reason I've read `A0` as `0A` :-S So you aren't missing something, I just need glasses :-)

Comment: I can get dots to work, but I can't get a class name starting with a number to work without the help of jQuery.  `document.querySelectorAll(".1")` throws a syntax error.  jQuery must be circumventing `document.querySelectorAll()` in this case.

Comment: @gilly3: jQuery does try `document.querySelectorAll()`. When it receives an exception, then it'll fall back to Sizzle automatically.

Answer (score 2):

As zerkms suggests, you can escape it but you need double backslashes:

```
$('.4\\.0\\.3')
```

Or for a less hacky solution, use an attribute selector instead:

```
$('[class~="4.0.3"]')
```